# Is there a way to control runnable thread from other component?

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I would like to know, whether we can control a runnable thread from other component. Say we have 2 java modules. In one module(A), I have a runnable thread which does some work. In the second module (B), I want to access it and get values. If both components are in a single module, there is no issue. But here both are separate modules. Module A have threads running, while module B depends on Module A and want to access it.

Is there any standard practice to do this? Or is it a bad design?

Edit : Modules/components means 2 maven projects.

Comment: Java doesn't have a concept of *modules* by itself, so you're going to have to explain better what you mean. The word *component* is pretty ambiguous too.

Comment: What do you mean by "control"? If you mean "invoke methods on", sure you can - you can do that anywhere you have a reference to the thread.

Comment: @Kayaman modules/components means 2 maven projects.

Comment: This isn't really related to threads, since the module shouldn't be concerned with the inner workings of the other module. It's just cross-module communication, which can be done in many, many ways (such as what eluleci proposes below).

Comment: @Kayaman, I look for a simpler way, rather putting a  messaging system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like event bus (ex: [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) or [GreenRobot](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)) to communicate and send-receive data across your modules.

But after some time it can be really hard to track which event is being sent from which part. For using event bus efficiently, you can check the [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/) architecture which is manly used in web apps. For Android you can check [this project](https://github.com/lgvalle/android-flux-todo-app) and modify it based on your needs.

Comment: But I don't want to put a messaging service bus between two modules. Looks for a simple way. Thanks